# STFT computation without using spectrogram function!

Tags: matlab

I was trying to plot STFT using plot3 in MATLAB but failed. Can somebody guide me how to do that? My MWE is given below:

```
%% STFT Computataion
clear; clc; clf;

%% Get input and calculate frame size and overlap/shift
[Y,Fs]=wavread('D_NEHU_F0001_MN_10001');
frame_size=round(20*Fs/1000);         % calculate frame size for 20ms
frame_shift=round(10*Fs/1000);        % calculate frame shift for 10ms

%% Plot the input signal in time domain
t=1/Fs:1/Fs:(length(Y)/Fs);
subplot(2,1,1)
    plot(t,Y);
    title('Speech signal in time domain');
    ylabel('Magnitude of samples');
    xlabel('time in seconds');

%% Calculation of STFT
%NoOfFrames=floor((length(Y)/frame_shift)-1);
NoOfFrames=length(Y)-frame_size;
j=1;
%for i=1:frame_shift:(length(Y)-frame_size)
for i=1:frame_shift:((length(Y)-frame_size))%+frame_shift)
    sp_frame=Y(i:(i+frame_size)).*hamming(frame_size+1);
    sp_frame_dft=abs(fft(sp_frame)); % Compute STFT
    sp_frame_array(:,j)=sp_frame_dft;
    j=j+1;
end

%% Plot the STFT in 3D
[rows,cols]=size(sp_frame_array);
F=linspace(1/Fs,Fs/2000,cols);
T=1/Fs:(frame_shift*Fs/1000):(cols*(frame_shift*Fs/1000));
Z=1:frame_size+1;
subplot(2,1,2)
    %mesh(sp_frame_array);
    %surf(sp_frame_array,'EdgeColor','none');
   plot3(T,F,sp_frame_array);
```

Comment: You should probably be using surf and not plot3. I see you did try surf in that code snippet, how did that look?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your question exactly is about, but I guess the problem is, with the provided code, that you do not get a plot similar to the one you'd get, say, with `surf`.

Furthermore, I am also not quite sure why you would want to use `plot3`, maybe to get the labels on the time and frequency right ? you could do that all the same with `surf`:

```
surf(T, F, sp_frame_array,'EdgeColor','none');
```

As a matter of fact, the reason why your `plot3` does not give the same figure is because the arguments of `plot3` must be three matrices of the same size (check it on `help plot3`). Your code should actually be broken on Matlab, which it's not, according to my test. Well, once again Matlab allowing people to mess around without warnings (*go Python!* :D)... Anyway, try to set the matrices more like the following:

```
F=linspace(1/Fs,Fs/2000, rows); % note: has to be rows, not cols here!
Fmat = F(:) * ones(1,cols); % or use repmat
T=1/Fs:(frame_shift*Fs/1000):(cols*(frame_shift*Fs/1000));
Tmat = ones(rows,1) * T(:)';

plot3(Tmat,Fmat,sp_frame_array);
```

While this will normally produce something more in line with what I would expect in drawing a spectrogram, I'd still make some remarks:

- your `F` vector should go up to `Fs`, because of the way you filled `sp_frame_dft` in. More specifically, it should go from 0Hz to `Fs - Fs/rows`:

  ```
  F = linspace(0,Fs*(1-1/rows)/1000,rows); % in kHz
  ```
- you would probably like to draw the amplitudes in dBs:

  ```
  plot3(Tmat,Fmat,db(sp_frame_array));
  ```

[image: plot3 result]

- `plot3` draws one line per column of the provided matrices. That means potentially lots of lines to draw! As @atul-ingle asked, are you sure this is what you want? Maybe `waterfall` would provide a better rendering at a lower cost?

  ```
  waterfall(T,F,db(sp_frame_array));
  ```

[image: waterfall result]

Well, you'll get the lines for the rows, instead of the columns, so you might need to transpose if the latter is what you want.

- You might also prefer to visualise only the first half of the matrix (because the frequencies higher than Fs/2 are only mirrors of the other half of the matrix).

Hope that helps!